# wordpress elementor plugin not loading site

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I installed wordpress.org from bitnami.com and i tried making a website with elementor plugin but when i activate elementor i can't load the webpage that i am running on localhost.
 How can i fix this ?

---

#### What i tried:

---

I tried going to wp-config.php and changing WP_DEBUG to true, i also tried removing all the plugins and only leaving elementor but it still the same problem.. my page loads only when i remove the elementor plugin. I switched the editor loader method to enable. My bitnami wordpress version is 5.9.3, PHP version 8.0.19, mariadb version 10.4.24, theme astra 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .htaccess file.
If You have this code and not working

Please check it, if you haven't this code please copy and paste this code and check.

```
#BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#END WordPress
```

Comment: where can i find this file ?

Comment: found it and this is whats inside

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Open the file in a code editor and paste the code and save it.